# Loading new scripts with Ajax-powered web-site

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've done the usual searches for previous answers... None found.

Basically I'm creating a website that loads each page into a content Div using jQuery.

Here's the site in progress http://www.websitesbyshane.co.uk/chris

Everything is working ok so far, my problem is that when the user clicks through to the 'portfolio' section, I would like to display some images using new scripts (a lightbox type script) however, it seems that by loading content into a div using ajax is preventing me from doing this. Anyone have any ideas for a solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Here's my Ajax script...

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('.top_nav a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('.top_nav a').click(function(){




    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('slow',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#header_resize').append('<span id="load">Please wait</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())

    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');


    }


    return false;

});
```

});

/* finish ajax */

Now, inside one of the #content Div's that will be loaded, I just want to add a lightbox type gallery which will include 1 additional .js file.  Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample of whatever scripts you're trying to apply, and how you're calling in the div contents with AJAX?

It seems like $.getScript() with a callback would suffice, but it's difficult to say.

Comment: This should make it clearer for you. 

It works great here!
http://websitesbyshane.co.uk/chris/portfolio.php

but not if accessed via an ajax call from 
http://websitesbyshane.co.uk/chris/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function. I've experienced this myself and knows this will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Where would i use this though? inside the #content div of the page to be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Is [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure. Basically, when I've loaded content into a div with ajax, I can no-longer use any scripts on the NEW content.. That's my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could, perhaps, use the `success` event of the ajax call, to initialize the gallery then..(*and pre-include the script in your page*)